# Cart total is showing NAN instead of Total price

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

So the problem I am currently facing is this. I have a Cart logic located in the CartContext. Everything works except the total number of prices it is displaying NAN. Here is the link to the CodeSandbox for a better understanding https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-sound-5y7pg?file=/src/CartItem.js:1486-1494.Please comment if something is wrong with sandbox

```
import React from "react";
function getCartFromLocalStorage() {
  return localStorage.getItem("cart")
    ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"))
    : [];
}

const CartContext = React.createContext();

function CartProvider({ children }) {
  const [cart, setCart] = React.useState(getCartFromLocalStorage());
  const [total, setTotal] = React.useState(0);
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));

    let newTotal = cart.reduce((total, cartItem) => {
      return (total += cartItem.amount * cartItem.price);
    }, 0);
    newTotal = parseFloat(newTotal.toFixed(2));
    setTotal(newTotal);
    // cart items
    let newCartItems = cart.reduce((total, cartItem) => {
      return (total += cartItem.amount);
    }, 0);
    setCartItems(newCartItems);
  }, [cart]);

  // global functions
  const removeItem = id => {
    setCart([...cart].filter(item => item.id !== id));
  };
  const increaseAmount = id => {
    const newCart = [...cart].map(item => {
      return item.id === id
        ? { ...item, amount: item.amount + 1 }
        : { ...item };
    });
    setCart(newCart);
  };
  const decreaseAmount = (id, amount) => {
    if (amount === 1) {
      removeItem(id);
      return;
    } else {
      const newCart = [...cart].map(item => {
        return item.id === id
          ? { ...item, amount: item.amount - 1 }
          : { ...item };
      });

      setCart(newCart);
    }
  };
  const addToCart = book => {
    const { id, image, by, bookName,RegularPrice } = book;
    const item = [...cart].find(item => item.id === id);

    if (item) {
      increaseAmount(id);
      return;
    } else {
      const newItem = { id, image, by, bookName, RegularPrice, amount: 1 };
      const newCart = [...cart, newItem];
      setCart(newCart);
    }
  };
  const clearCart = () => {
    setCart([]);
  };
  return (
    <CartContext.Provider
      value={{
        cart,
        cartItems,
        total,
        removeItem,
        increaseAmount,
        decreaseAmount,
        addToCart,
        clearCart
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  );
}

export { CartContext, CartProvider };
```

Cart Item

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import {Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
import { CartContext } from "../../context/cart";
import { FaAngleDown, FaAngleUp } from "react-icons/fa";
import Checkout from "./Checkout";
export default function CartItem({ id, image,bookName, RegularPrice, by, amount }) {
  const { removeItem, increaseAmount, decreaseAmount } = React.useContext(
    CartContext
  );
  return (
      <div id={id} className="cart__item">
          <img className='cart__image' src={image}  />
        <div className='cart__itemdesc'>
         <h4>{bookName}</h4>
        <h6 className='cart__by'>By: {by}</h6>
        <button
          className="cart__removebtn"
          onClick={() => {
            removeItem(id);
          }}
         >
          Remove
        </button>
        <div>
        <button
          className="cart-btn amount-btn"
          onClick={() => {
            increaseAmount(id);
          }}
        >
          <FaAngleUp />
        </button>
        <p className="item-amount">{amount}</p>
        <button
          className="cart-btn amount-btn"
          onClick={() => {
            decreaseAmount(id, amount);
          }}
        >
          <FaAngleDown />
        </button>
      </div>
        </div>  
        <span className='circle'><span className='circleone'></span></span>
        <span className='cart__regular'>{RegularPrice}</span>      
        <div>   
        <Checkout />
        </div>    
    </div>
  );
}
```

Checkout

```
import React,{useContext} from 'react'
import { CartContext } from '../../context/cart'
import {Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'
import EmptyCart from './EmptyCart';

const Checkout = () => {
  const history = useHistory()
  const {cart, total} = useContext(CartContext)
  if (cart.length === 0) {
    return <EmptyCart />;
  }

    return (
        <div className='checkout'>
            <h2>Summary</h2>
            <h2>Subtotal : ${total}</h2>
            <Link to='/stripecontainer' className='checkout__btnOne'>Proceed to Checkout</Link>            
        </div>
    )
}

export default Checkout
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the ``NaN`` issue in your sandbx, give a bit more context maybe?

Comment: Where is the "total number of prices" stored/shown? If it's not in the code here on Stack Overflow, I can't see it, which is one of the many reasons we expect all relevant code to be available on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey. I updated the code

Comment: is this what you were aiming for

Comment: I was hoping that you would also point out what line you were seeing the NaN. As @Luca noted, they are unable to reproduce, and you say, "total number of prices" but I'm guessing you mean "subtotal"?

Comment: yes I meant subtotal